# Is possible to "skip" needed class?

Tags: c++, class

I'm newbie in C++ and I have no idea how to put it in google to search but, i have code:

**player:**

```
class Player {
public:
    bool armor_set[4];
    short int protection;
    void EquipArmor(short int, Armor);
};

void Player::EquipArmor(short int armor_slot, Armor armoridx) {
    this->armor_set[armor_slot] = true;
    this->protection += armoridx.addingarmor;
}
```

**armor:**

```
constexpr short int ARMOR_SET_HELMET = 1;
constexpr short int ARMOR_SET_CHEST = 2;
constexpr short int ARMOR_SET_LEGS = 3;
constexpr short int ARMOR_SET_BOOTS = 4;


class Armor {
public:
    string name;
    short int addingarmor;
    short int armor_type;
}

Armor::AddArmor(string name, short int adding, short int type) {
    this->name = name;
    this->addingarmor += adding;
    this->armor_type = type; 
}
```

And my question is, is possible to make `Player::UnequipArmor` without needing class? Something like:

```
void Player::UnequipArmor(short int armor_slot) {
    this->armor_set[armor_slot] = false;
    this->protection -= ... ???
}
```

? Thank you for any answer.

Comment: So you are asking to write a new method for the class without manipulating the class itself?

Comment: `Player::UnequipArmor` is a method of the class `Player`. You could add it since it seems doesn't exist yet. You could as well implement your own code out of  `Player` class but then, if you want to do something with a player you are limited to what the `Player` class interface (public method and members) offers you ( let you use).

Comment: Note that `armor_set[armor_slot]` with `armor slot` being `ARMOR_SET_BOOTS` (if that's how it would be used), that is, 4, accesses the 5th element of `armor_set` (indexes in C run from 0..n-1). It would be better to use an enumeration for this. Enumeration elements start with the value 0 anyway, by default.

Comment: Oh. Yea you are right, I somehow miss it.  `ARMOR_SET_HELMET` should start with 0 not 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remember the values in `armor_set` itself when equipping the armor pieces.

Either just convert it to `short armorset[4]` and have a special value, probably 0, for denoting the armor is not equipped. `EquipArmor` will write the value there, instead of just setting it to `true`.

Or the if `Armor.addingarmor` can have any value, you can use `std::optional` which would make the armor's equipness(?) more clear.

In both cases, the `protection` member becomes kinda obsolete, you can keep it as a cache, but just having `int compute()` public method which computes the value on fly won't hurt.